# Close a Windows Phone HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8, crash

I am writing an HTML5 app for windows phone and I have run into a problem.  The app runs a lengthy operation so I have the lock screen idle disabled.  I would like the app to shut itself off after one hour so that the user does not have to babysit their phone.  The problem is that Microsoft has disabled window.close().

I have two ideas on how to work around this:

1.) Use a javascript infinite loop that runs after one hour to crash the app.

2.) Use a javascript function that will keep the phone idle for one hour then stop, allowing the phone to idle and then close.

For the first option, I used this wrapped in a timeout:

```
txt = "a";
while(1){
txt = txt += "a";
}
```

But it fails to crash the app, it just hangs it up for a moment, but then when I touch anything in the app it will crash, so I thought I was smart and set another function to click the same element in the app after an additional 10 seconds, but that does not produce the crash.

I also tried this:

```
while(true);
```

and apparently this is just too intensive and it just freezes the app, and this time touching the app does nothing as it is completely frozen until I hit the back button to close the app.

Does anyone know a debug location for IE mobile that forces a crash, or a javascript function that will crash the browser.  Yes I know this is a terrible option, but I don't know why Microsoft disabled window.close()

For the second option I have come up with nothing.  Is it even possible to keep the phone idle from an HTML5 app?

Comment: What do you mean, "shut itself off"? Crashing the application doesn't seem like a good choice for any application. Why does it need to shut itself off instead of just not doing any more work?

Comment: I made an app to fix stuck pixels and screen burn in and to do this I disabled the lock screen, but I also wanted the user to have the option to have the app close after one hour so that the screen would then turn off and they didn't have to babysit it.  Apparently closing an app from within the app is not allowed in the store policy so window.close is disabled.  MS wants users to use the hardware key.  My only option was to make the app crash after one hour if the option was selected.  Now I can tell if people are actually using the app by the crash reports lol.

Comment: It might not make it through the app submission when they see your app crash. Why can't your app just "finish" and be done with it? This doesn't seem like an app that you'd run more than once anyway and they should probably leave their phone plugged in.

Comment: It made it through and got published with three updates already (knock on wood).  The crashing is hidden on a blank, black page and seems like it is a function of the app.  It's an HTML5 app so there's no way to communicate between VB and JS that the process is done and the lock screen can be re-enabled.  The lock screen is either enabled or disabled and if it is enabled then the screen will just turn off even if a JS process is running.  I have a Lumia 925 and the burn in on the AMOLED drives me crazy.  It was originally just something that I made for myself, but decided to publish it.